# Is there any way to make custom struct<type> - like structure on C++?

Tags: c++

There are some structures in C++ which instances can be defined as

`my_structure<type> variable;`

For example, std::vector

`std::vector<int> very_important_vector;`

And I would like to know is there any way to make my custom structure, class, or whatever definable as shown above.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates

Comment: You're probably going to want a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: the question reads a bit like "Can I get a hammer?" while it is not clear what nail you want to get into which wall. Templates are much more than generic containers.

Answer (score 4):

> is there any way to make my custom structure, class, or whatever definable as shown above.

Yes, these are called [**class templates**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template). One example is given below:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct my_structure
{
    //members here
};

int main ()
{
  //now you can write 
  my_structure<int> variable;//this will instantiate my_structure<int> 
  
  my_structure<float> variable2; //this will instantiate my_structure<float>
}
```